# Splitting list down to find the 'bad apple' - working with list sets

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0, batch-processing

I am trying to split a list into sets to find the few items in the set that don't satisfy a condition. Specifically, I am importing files into a system, and the only way I know that files are corrupt is that the system throws an exception if there is a bad file in the batch. I have no idea before hand what the bad file might be. SO I am trying to split the batches down half by half, narrowing down what the bad files could be.

I just can't wrap my head around it although I feel I am close. I can't get it to return from the method because the bad file list equals the temp list. Any ideas?

```
private void AddBadFilesToVaultInChunks(List<ImportItem> filesToProcess, int chunk, int batchCount)
{
    // m_badFiles is a list of files where the batches failed.
    badFileCountBefore = m_badFiles.Count;
    int batchNum = 1;
    int count = 0;
    // create a list of files that have bad files in them in _this_ batch.
    List<ImportItem> intermList = new List<ImportItem>();
    foreach (IEnumerable<ImportItem> files in filesToProcess.Chunk(chunk))
    {
        try
        {
            PerformAddOnBadFiles(AddFlags, batchCount, ref batchNum, ref count, files, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // add the files to the bad batch - we have bad files here.
            intermList.AddRange(files);
        }
    }    
// this isn't the way to do this - the count may be the same. I have also tried SequenceEqual().
    if (intermList.Count > 0 && (badFileCountBefore != badFileCountAfter))    
    {                
        chunk = chunk / 2;
        if (chunk == 0)
            chunk = intermList.Count;
        batchCount = (intermList.Count + chunk - 1) / chunk;                
        AddBadFilesToVaultInChunks(intermList, chunk, batchCount);
    }
}
```

Where I do the add; I remove the good files that didn't cause an exception from the bad;

```
private void PerformAddOnBadFiles(int AddFlags, int batchCount, ref int batchNum, ref int count, IEnumerable<ImportItem> files)
{    
    try
    {         
        // perform the add
        int fileCount = batchAdd.CommitAdd(();
        while (fileCount == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }        
        // remove the good files from the bad
        m_badFiles = m_badFiles.Except(files).ToList();
        badFileCountAfter = m_badFiles.Count;        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
        throw;                
    }
    finally
    {
        batchNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider cleaning up your code a little bit - there are two parameters to `PerformAddOnBadFiles` (`batchCount` and `count`) that aren't used. Also consider adding xml summary tags to your methods to describe what they do and what each parameter is for (see the example in my answer below).

Comment: I probably should have cleaned it up, but the parameters that are there are used in my code. I removed portions of it that don't pertain to the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive that I understand the problem correctly, but here is how I would do it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Container for any bad files that fail during import
/// </summary>
public static List<ImportItem> badFiles = new List<ImportItem>();

/// <summary>
/// Imports a list of files
/// </summary>
/// <param name="files">The list of files to import</param>
/// <param name="chunkSize">The number of files to try to import at one time</param>
public static void ImportFiles(List<ImportItem> files, int chunkSize)
{
    if (files == null || files.Count == 0) return;   

    int startIndex = 0; // Start from the beginning of the list

    while (startIndex < files.Count)
    {
        // Adjust chunkSize in case we're trying to get 
        // more files from the list than it contains
        if (chunkSize + startIndex > files.Count)
        {
            chunkSize = files.Count - startIndex;
        }

        // Get the next 'chunk' of files to import
        List<ImportItem> filesChunk = files.GetRange(startIndex, chunkSize);

        try
        {
            // Import the chunk of files
            // Note: All this method should do is attempt to 
            // import the files and throw an exception if the import
            // fails. No need to modify a bunch of global variables.
            ImportFilesChunk(filesChunk);
        }
        catch
        {
            // At least one of the files in this chunk failed
            if (filesChunk.Count == 1)
            {
                // We're down to one file, so add it to
                // the 'bad files' list and continue on
                badFiles.Add(filesChunk[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Use a smaller chunk size to split this chunk further
                var newChunkSize = (chunkSize / 2) + (chunkSize % 2); // Round up if chunkSize is odd
                ImportFiles(filesChunk, newChunkSize);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Move start position to the position just 
            // after the chunk we just processed
            startIndex += chunkSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's obvious I was over-thinking this. I appreciate the time you took out to help. Thanks.